# Message Compression in ActiveMQ STOMP Client

Tags: jms, message-queue, activemq-classic, activemq-cpp

Is it possible to implement text message compression on publishing to a queue/topic(with out modifying the server or consumer)? I want to know if the existing Java STOMP client or CPP STOMP Client (ActiveMQ-CPP) supports the message compression?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current Stomp spec doesn't define any standardized form of compression for message body data.  This means that there's no way to create reliable and inter-operable Stomp client's that compress the data.   You can of course compress the data yourself and set a header that tells your various client's what the content type is much like the HTTP spec outlines.